# ant Permission Denied problem

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ant, centos

After extracting and saving the ant files into an opt/ directory and setting the path variable
to `$ANT_HOME/bin`

I ran the following command on a CentOS 5

```
ant -version
```

and I am getting the following error

```
-bash:/path/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant: Permission denied
```

Is there some permission I am supposed to set or some typical source of this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you own the file, try

```
chmod u+x /path/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant
```

If someone else owns it, either `sudo` or become root then

```
chmod 755 /path/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant
```

You need to have execute permissions on the file; the first gives execute permissions to the owner only and is probably preferable if you own the file and are the only one that uses it.  The second requires root privileges and gives execute and read permission to everyone, plus write permission to the owner.

You can view the current permissions and ownership of the file by running `ls -l /path/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant`.